# Adjust code that uses data.table function

Tags: r, data.table

The code below uses the `data.table` function to generate an output table. However, I would like to know if it is possible to optimize the code somehow and still get the same result? The idea is to reduce the code in order to decrease the processing time.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

df1 <- structure(
  list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-06-25","2021-06-25","2021-06-27","2021-07-07","2021-07-07","2021-07-09","2021-07-09","2021-07-09"),
       Code = c("FDE","ABC","ABC","ABC","CDE","FGE","ABC","CDE"),
       Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday","Friday"),
       DR1 = c(4,1,4,3,6,4,3,5),
       DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6), DR02= c(4,2,6,7,3,2,7,4),DR03= c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5),
       DR04 = c(5,4,3,3,6,2,1,9),DR05 = c(5,4,5,3,6,2,1,9),
       DR06 = c(2,4,3,3,5,6,7,8),DR07 = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8),
       DR08 = c(4,0,0,1,2,4,4,4),DR09 = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8),DR010 = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8),DR011 = c(4,7,3,2,2,7,7,7), 
       DR012 = c(4,4,2,3,0,4,4,5),DR013 = c(4,4,1,4,0,3,2,0),DR014 = c(0,3,1,2,0,2,NA,NA)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

selection = startsWith(names(df1), "DR0")

df1[selection][is.na(df1[selection])] = 0

dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)

cols <- grep("^DR0", colnames(dt1), value = TRUE)

medi_ana <- 
  dt1[, (paste0(cols, "_PV")) := DR1 - .SD, .SDcols = cols
  ][, lapply(.SD, median), by = .(Code, Week), .SDcols = paste0(cols, "_PV") ]

f1 <- function(nm, pat) grep(pat, nm, value = TRUE)
nm1 <- f1(names(df1), "^DR0\\d+$")
nm2 <- f1(names(medi_ana), "_PV")
nm3 <- paste0("i.", nm2)
setDT(df1)[medi_ana,  (nm2) := Map(`+`, mget(nm1), mget(nm3)), on = .(Code, Week)]
SPV1 <- df1[, c('date1', 'date2', 'Code', 'Week', nm2), with = FALSE]

dmda<-"2021-07-09"
code<-"CDE"

SPV2<-melt(SPV1[date2 == dmda & Code == code][, 
   lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = Code, 
   .SDcols = patterns("^DR0")],
    id.var = "Code", variable.name = "name", value.name = "val")[, 
      name := readr::parse_number(as.character(name))][]

 > SPV2
    Code name val
 1:  CDE    1   5
 2:  CDE    2   5
 3:  CDE    3   5
 4:  CDE    4   5
 5:  CDE    5   5
 6:  CDE    6   5
 7:  CDE    7   5
 8:  CDE    8   5
 9:  CDE    9   5
10:  CDE   10   5
11:  CDE   11   5
12:  CDE   12   5
13:  CDE   13   5
14:  CDE   14   5

result <- SPV2 %>% 
    group_by(Code) %>% 
    slice((as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Code == first(Code)])):max(name)+1) %>%
    ungroup

> result

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Code   name   val
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 CDE      12     5
2 CDE      13     5
3 CDE      14     5
```

Comment: Only the last part uses `dplyr`.  You can change it to data.table as `SPV2[na.omit(SPV2[, .I[(as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [
      df1$Code == first(Code)])):max(name)+1], .(Code)]$V1)]`

Comment: $V1? Could you please leave it in answer format?

Comment: this is not a specific programming question. code review, editing, optimization, etc are off topic for this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dplyr` code can be converted to `data.table` as

```
SPV2[na.omit(SPV2[, .I[(as.Date(dmda) - min(as.Date(df1$date1) [ 
         df1$Code == first(Code)])):max(name)+1], .(Code)]$V1)]
```

-output

```
    Code  name   val
   <char> <num> <num>
1:    CDE    12     5
2:    CDE    13     5
3:    CDE    14     5
```